# Running a jar file from java code

Tags: java, jar, jetty

I am trying to run a jar file from a java code but it does not work.
I have tried the Runtime and th ProcessBuilder but it failed to start.
the jar is the start.jar file for the Jetty Web Server

Any Help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your use case but I think you are trying to start a Jetty server and in my humble opinion the best option for this situation is using Jetty as a dependency. Please put that jar file in your classpath and add these lines in your code.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

and from Runtime,

```
String directory = "[jetty directory]";
String format = "/usr/bin/java -Djetty.logging.dir=%s/logs -Djetty.home=%s -Djetty.base=%s -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar %s/start.jar jetty.state=%s/jetty.state jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml";

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                     .exec(String.format(format, directory, directory, directory, directory, directory));

process.waitFor();
```

Comment: I m not trying the embeded way,  I have download the jetty server and to run it you have to tape java -jar start.jar in line command.
And i am trying to do from the a java code

Comment: please check the answer again.

Comment: Don't make `jetty.home` and `jetty.base` the same directory.  That's bad form and not future proof.

Comment: Can i stopped the server from java also ?